# Interceptor Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un interceptor spinner, para cada request. Esto me funciona excelente y demas cada vez que hay una peticion.
El problema me surge ahora que necesito, en una pantalla determinada,que no ande el spinner:
Es decir, en una pantalla tengo que hacer unos filtros, que si o si se van a comunicar al backend,no puedo traer toda la data y guardala y filtrar despues en cache, porque es variable con fechas y demas.
Como si o si, se tiene que llamar al backend, va a salir el spinner, pero en este caso no quiero que salga.

**Hay alguna forma de cancelar a voluntad ese interceptor?**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la clase `HttpBackend` para realizar la petición. En la documentación se especifica que:

```
Los interceptores se ubican entre la interfaz `HttpClient` y `HttpBackend`.
`HttpBackend` envía las peticiones directamente al backend por medio de las APIs del navegador, sin utilizar la cadena de interceptores.
```

En el servicio podrías, entonces, hacer lo siguiente:

```
...

export class EjemploService {

  private httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor(httpBackend: HttpBackend) { 
     this.httpClient = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
  }

  hacerPeticion(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      `http://localhost:4200/ejemplo/${id}`
    );
 }

...
```

Solo trata de que se diferencie bien que peticiones utilizan los interceptores y cuáles no.

Otra alternativa es en el interceptor del spinner, incluir un arreglo de urls por las cuales se debe ignorar el spinner. Algo así:

```
...
// URLs que no deben mostrar el spinner.
skipUrls = [
    '/ejemplo',
];

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    for (const skipUrl of this.skipUrls) {
        if (new RegExp(skippUrl).test(request.url)) {
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }

    // El resto del código

}
...
```

Cual usar ya dependerá del caso de uso y preferencia.

Comment: buenas, me ayudarias con este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455273/angular-interceptor-para-errores-500